# How to Make Structure as Null in C#?

Tags: c#

How to Make Structure as Null in C# ?

```
EMPLOYEE? objEmployee = null;  
EMPLOYEE stEmployee = objEmployee.GetValueOrDefault();
```

but this make `stEmployee` fields as null,but i want to make this structure as null.
It shows `stEmployee.FirstName =  null`,`stEmployee.LastName =  null`

But i want to make `stEmployee` as null.
How to achieve that ?

Comment: Use a class (recommended) or replace all instances of `EMPLOYEE` with `EMPLOYEE?`. Also as a side note, `EMPLOYEE` doesn't follow C# style rules and should be `Employee` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Structs are value objects in C#. If you require them to be nullable, you need to use the syntax `EMPLOYEE?`

Answer (score 1):

Struct is value type - not reference type. All value types cannot be assigned to null.

["Value Types" article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

Comment: It's possible by wrapping the value type in a `Nullable<EMPLOYEE>` class. C# provides some nice syntax for this too - `EMPLOYEE?`

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but Nullable<EMPLOYEE> is not a struct anymore :) With the same result he can create new class with property of type EMPLOYEE and assign null to and instance of that class.

Comment: @RobertRouhani and Pavel: `Nullable<T>` is a struct, not a class.

Comment: @phoog oh, you're right, just read article about nullable struct - that was interesting :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` can't be null in the same way that an int can't be null, and a float can't be null - they're all value types! But in the same way that you can make a `nullable` type in C# you can face to `struct`:

When you want to have an integer type with ability of accepting null values you should follow below code:

```
int? x = null;
```

and then you can check it as below, and also you have access to its value through x.Value

```
if ( x != null)
{
    //then do blah-blah with x.Value
    Console.Write(x.Value * 2);
}
```

Now you can do the same thing with struct...

```
struct Book
{
   public string title;
   ...
}
...
Book book0 = null; //It doesn't work
Book? book1 = null; //It works
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) type, which is available from .NET2.

The reason is because reference types value can be set to zeros, which would indicate that the reference type does not point to anything, it is then NULL. With the value type, you cannot simply say that it's value is all zeros, for example all zeros for an Int32 would mean just 0 value.

The main difference is for value types you directly assign **value**, for reference type you only assign a "**memory pointer**" to the value. Nullable can only be used with value types and it uses extra bit to store information whether the type is null (HasValue) or not.